# How to add a hover effect on a dropdown?

Tags: css, liquid

I'm currently designing a new website and I added a dropdown which works perfectly fine when clicked. I basically want it to show that dropdown when hovered.

What I tried was:

```css
{% include 'currency-picker' %}
                <style>
           .currency-picker {
            background-color: transparent;
            font-size: 12pt;
            font:Montserrat;
            letter-spacing: 2px;
            color: black;
             }
           .currency-picker:hover {
            display: block;
   }
           .currency-picker:hover { 
            background-color: white;
```

This is the dropdown itself:

```html
<label class="currency-picker__wrapper">
  <span class="currency-picker__label"></span>
  <select class="currency-picker" name="currencies" style="display: inline; width: auto; vertical-align: inherit;">
  {% assign codes = 'USD,EUR,GBP,CAD,ARS,AUD,BBD,BDT,BSD,BHD,BRL,BOB,BND,BGN,ILS,MMK,KYD,CLP,CNY,COP,CRC,HRK,CZK,DKK,DOP,XCD,EGP,XPF,FJD,GHS,GTQ,GYD,GEL,HKD,HUF,ISK,INR,IDR,NIS,JMD,JPY,JOD,KZT,KES,KWD,LVL,LTL,MXN,MYR,MUR,MDL,MAD,MNT,MZN,ANG,NZD,NGN,NOK,OMR,PKR,PYG,PEN,PHP,PLN,QAR,RON,RUB,SAR,RSD,SCR,SGD,SYP,ZAR,KRW,LKR,SEK,CHF,TWD,THB,TZS,TTD,TRY,UAH,AED,UYU,VEB,VND,ZMK' | split: ',' %}
  {% assign supported_codes = settings.supported_currencies | split: ' ' %}
  <option value="{{ shop.currency }}" selected="selected">{{ shop.currency }}</option>
  {% for code in supported_codes %}
    {% if code != shop.currency and codes contains code %}
    <option value="{{ code }}">{{ code }}</option>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
  </select>
</label>
```

The strange thing is, that the *.currency-picker:hover { 
            background-color: white;* works and it does indeed show the white background when hovered.

Is there anyone knowing a solutions of my problem?

Have a nice day and best regards,

Ismael

Comment: It may be a simple typo. Your css above has `.currency-picker: hover` but it should have `.currency-picker:hover` (with no extra space). If the same typo is in your code, fixing that may fix the problem.

Comment: Hi  arbuthnott. Thank you for your reply. No it's not the typo as there is no space in the code on the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at your code, is there any reason why you don't just use the same markup as the other dropdowns? Consistency is always key.

What you are trying to do does not work or is not allowed in the browser. Instead of using an actual "select" box, I would use the actual markup they are using on the other dropdowns which give you the exact functionality that you are looking for.

This code (taken from your site) should give you a clue on how to handle this. Also You ave an extra starting script tag on your page where you dropped that new test code..

Please note I changed the below code a bit to give you better reference. If you were to drop this code into your site, it would work, but you need to refactor it to make it dynamic.

```
<li class="site-nav__item site-nav__expanded-item site-nav--has-dropdown" aria-haspopup="true">
<a href="/collections/for-her" class="site-nav__link">USD <span class="icon icon-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
<ul class="site-nav__dropdown text-left">

<li>
    <a href="/collections/bags" class="site-nav__dropdown-link">EUR</a>
</li>

<li>
    <a href="/collections/high-heels" class="site-nav__dropdown-link">CHF</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

After my change...
[image: changes]

Comment: Hi Judson, thank you for your reply. It would be great if you could show me the code as I have 0 experience with java.

Comment: Hi Judson, thank you for your edit and the code, but unfortunately it is still not willing to work.

Comment: Can you put a console.log inside that event function to make sure you're seeing any response

Comment: Also can you show me the code that you implemented?

Comment: And another thing are you using JQuery? If you can give me a link to your site where that code as I can probably fix it and send you the correct code

Comment: Hi Judson, the site URL is: https://csp-fashion.com/ and the psw is: csp. Yes jQuery is installed. The implemented code can be found here: https://codeshare.io/5NexP9

Comment: I will look in the morning. I do not know what time zone you're in but is very late here but I promise I will look

Comment: Please see latest comments

Comment: Hi Judson, thank you very much for your great support. I understood why it wasn't working.

Comment: No problem!! :)